# converting html into php conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am using a wordpress plugin that requires the following code in my template:

```
<li><a href="#"><?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
                    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('shanti', 'two-image')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('shanti', 'two-image', NULL,  'big'); 
                endif; ?></a></li>
```

Basically, it says "if the MultiPost Thumbnails class exists, then display the 'big' image."  Im not too great with PHP, but I would like to include the `<li><a href="#">` within the conditional statement. Reason is because if there is no image to spit out, I dont want a blank `<li>` to be displayed. Any idea how to rewrite this code to include the `<li>/<a>` in the conditional?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [advanced escaping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php#example-64):

```
<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
                && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('shanti', 'two-image')): ?>
<li><a href="#">
    <?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('shanti', 'two-image', NULL,  'big'); ?>
</a></li> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thats it, i will accept your answer in a few minutes. thanks!

Comment: Or just use "echo" and be neater.

Comment: @Mike Nah this is the style they use in wordpress and is recommended by WP Coding Standards ;)